# Headless rendering/raytracing of 3D animations

Tags: linux, 3d, animation

I am looking for a 3D rendering/raytracing program that:

1. Runs on Linux
2. Does not force me to use a GUI
3. Can read all job details from a plain text ('job') file

What I would like to do is install the software onto a headless/virtual server, programmatically generate the job file locally, upload the job file to the server for processing, and then download the rendered animation when it is complete.

- No GUI should be required to configure or set up the software, or to set up or run any jobs.  The software should be fully configurable and controllable from the command line.
- No control or monitoring of the software is required whilst it is rendering.

The type of animation I want to do has a focus on **light** and **shadows**.  Imagine recreating something like [this time-lapse of a room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loVGi_bftdU).  Light sources and cameras will be animated.  Most other objects will be static.

Alternatively, is there a 'new way' of programmatically rendering scenes and animations that has appeared over the last decade or so that I might not be aware of, and should consider?